# Play Framework 2.1.x CascadeType.DETACH

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while but i can't seem to find anyone with similar problems.

I have a Person which contains multiple LogEntries. When i remove the person, i still want to keep the log entries intact.

In Person.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
private List<LogEntry> logEntries;
```

In LogEntry.java:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JsonIgnore
private Person person;
```

Is  it even possible to do this? I get a persistance error complaining about the foreign key, which is understandable since there won't be any relation anymore. But i'm wondering if its even possible?

tl;dr

I want to remove  the person, but keep the log entries but get persistance error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are in a mistake:

From [ObjectDB JPA help](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach)

> Detached entity objects are objects in a special state in which they
>   are not managed by any EntityManager but still represent objects in
>   the database.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Marking a reference field with CascadeType.DETACH (or CascadeType.ALL, which includes DETACH) indicates that detach operations should be cascaded automatically to entity objects that are referenced by that field

So, *detach* is *unload object from entity manager*. If you wan't to *deatch (**remove the link**) a Person from its logEntries* you must do it by hand.

To do it, you can use a [JPQL Update Query](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/update) before remove *Person* element. By example (*warning*, **not tested!!**):

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
     "UPDATE LogEntry log SET log.person = null where log.person = :person");
query.setParameter("person", person);
int updateCount = query.executeUpdate();
em.remove(person);
```

**Notes**:

- Use this code inside a **transactional code**
- *Update Queries* **doesn't notificate *update events* to *JPA listeners***  (like `@PrePersist` and `@PostPersist` annotated methods)
- As [is described here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event#Implementation_Restrictions_), **you shouldn't use *JPA listeners* to perform any operation on the entityManager**, so you shouldn't use `@PreRemove` on *Person* entity to clear *LogEntity* relationship.

Comment: Thank you! You answered my question in every aspect, would upvote if i could and will make sure to come back when i can.